# pandas how can I group rows accordingly to certain values in columns expressed as string

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have a pandas dataframe containing postcodes of london and surrounding areas.
my goal is to divide this daframe into 7 zones accordigly to the postecode. EX: NorthWest, all the postcodes starting with: (NW1, NW2, NW3,...NW11). 
I know how to drop rows,

```
x = dataset.drop(dataset[dataset['Postcode'].str.contains("NW1")].index)
```

but I need to keep only this rows.

Moreover, if I try to drop(just as an example, I need to keep the these rows)multiple rows

```
dataset_no_center = dataset.drop(dataset[dataset['Postcode'].str.contains("WC1")].index, dataset[dataset['Postcode'].str.contains("WC2")].index)
```

I get an error

how can I group rows accordigly to certain values in columns expressed as string

Comment: Can you guarantee that the post code *starts with* the prefixes, or only that it is contained somewhere in the string?

Comment: yes I erased everything but the first 3 characters. the result is this: 

Postcode:                      "KT2"